# How to compute an average using a while loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So I have a very specific assignment in my intro programing class. I'm suppose to calculate the  average of five "game scores" using a while loop and one prompt box. then I have to insert my code into a function and have then call that function using a button. I've been going crazy trying to get it to work and I'm pretty sure it's probably a simple error that's holding me back which makes it all the more frustrating.

```js
function Q1() {
  var sum = 0;
  var avg = 0;
  var sc1 = 0;
  var x = 1;

  alert("problem #2 find the average of five game scores");

  while (x < 5) {
    sc1 = prompt("enter the score from game # " + x);
    sum = parseFloat(sc1) + parseFloat(sum);
    avg = sum / x;
    x = x++;
    document.write(avg);
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="button" value="run problem #2" onClick="Q1()" ;/>
```

Comment: `x=x++` is probably going to double increment the value of x, skipping every other element.  You should either do `x=x+1` or `x++`.  Does that solve it?

Comment: `x=x++`  This does not do what you think it does.  `x++` will increment `x`, and then return the *original* value of `x`.  You are then setting `x` to that *original* value.  This is the same as doing `x=x`.

Comment: @mrrogers: Actually `x=x++` is going to do nothing.  It's like doing `x=x`.

Comment: Not a good idea to use *document.write* after the page has loaded. It will clear the **entire** content of the page (i.e. from opening HTML tag to close) and replace it with whatever you pass to it.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your helpful comments I've actually learned more in the time it took me to read them then the entire hour I spent in class. I'll be using this problem as a reference going forward. I'm curious though what should I use instead of document.write?

Comment: @ChristopherMedeiros—write it to the page, e.g. if you have a span with id "msgNode": `document.getElementById('msgNode').innerHTML = average;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few mistakes in your code.

- You are doing only 4 times you start at 1 and end at 4 (x<5)
- Move the math that should run once after the loop
- You don't have to parseFloat sum, you can be sure it's a float already, it starts at 0 and you add only floats to it.

#### Your code fixed:

```
function Q1() {
  var scores = 0;
  var x = 1;
  alert("problem #2 find the average of five game scores");
  while (x <= 5) {
    scores += parseFloat(prompt("enter the score from game # " + x));
    x++;
  }
  document.write(scores/5);
}
```

#### Or:

```
function Q1() {
  var average = 0;
  alert("problem #2 find the average of five game scores");
  for (var x=0; x < 5; x++) 
    average += parseFloat(prompt("enter the score from game # " + x))/5;
  document.write(average);
}
```

#### Even better, dont' hard-code the 5

```
function Q1(games) {
  var average = 0;
  alert("problem #2 find the average of five game scores");
  for (var x=0; x < games; x++) 
    average += parseFloat(prompt("enter the score from game # " + x))/games;
  document.write(average);
}
```

Comment: Could use `x < 5` if starts from `x = 0`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG But his x is set to 1!

Comment: This meets the requirements of my assignment. Thank you very much. But just out of my own curiosity could I use x for document.write(scores/5); or do I always have to write that number?

Comment: @ChristopherMedeiros `x` is the counter.

Comment: @NabilKadimi— hence "if". ;-)

Comment: @RobG It makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for finding average of 5 no,you have done silly mistake:

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="button" value="run problem #2" onClick="Q1()";/></br>
<script type= "text/javascript">
function Q1(){
var sum= 0;
var avg= 0;
var sc1= 0;
var x = 0;

alert ("problem #2 find the average of five game scores");

while(x < 5){
 sc1=prompt("enter the score from game # " + (x+1));    
     sum = parseFloat(sc1)+sum;
x++;  
}
 avg = sum/5;
 document.write(avg);
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consistent indenting will greatly increase the readability of your code (use spaces, not tabs).

Comment: this is not my code ,i only edited the Christopher Medeiros's code for solving his problem.....

Answer (score 0):

The way the variables was used on the original is kind of confusing, so this is what I suggest.

*HTML*

```
<input type="button" value="run problem #2" onClick="Q1()"/>
<br/>
```

*JS*

```
function Q1(){
    var sum= 0;
    var avg= 0;
    var score= 0;
    var x = 1;
    var g = 5;

    alert ("problem #2 find the average of five game scores");

    while(x <= g){
        score=prompt("enter the score from game # "+x);    
        sum += parseFloat(score);
        x++;  
    }
    avg = sum /g;
    document.write("Average is " + avg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<script>
function Q1() {
  var sum = 0;
  var avg = 0;
  var sc1 = 0;
  var x = 0;

  alert("problem #2 find the average of five game scores");

  while (x < 5) {
    sc1 = prompt("enter the score from game # " + (x+1));
    sum = parseFloat(sc1) + parseFloat(sum);
    x++;
  }
 avg = sum / x;
 document.write(avg);
};
</script>
```